# Qi Receiver on PCB

Tags: pcb, coil, wireless-charging

I'm looking at implementing Qi charging in my project, would it be possible to have a Qi receiver directly on the back of the PCB (copper traces in the shape of a coil)? Could this interfere with the electronics on the front of the PCB?

Comment: If it is possible with PCB traces rather than wires basically depends on how many turns you are supposed to fit into what "thickness".  And yes, the traces or even just being in the charger's field could interfere with particularly sensitive circuitry - it depends on what they are.  In practice, devices which are intended to work this way probably aren't very susceptible at the frequencies used for charging.

Comment: I doubt you get the needed inductance (the typical Qi receiver coils are in the order of 5 to 15 µH) on a PCB, esp. since the need to handle more than 1A current. Another indication: if it would be possible, some manufacturer would have done that to save cost. And AFAICS even the cheapest Qi receivers on ebay don't do that.